# Append same HTMLDivElement inside two divs

Tags: javascript, html

How do I append same `HTMLDivElement` inside two divs? In the example below only the `enemyGrid` is filled with divs (or only `userGrid` if I change the order)
Am I missing something?

```js
const gridRows = 10
const gridCols = 10
const userGrid = document.querySelector('.user-grid')
const enemyGrid = document.querySelector('.enemy-grid')

generateGrids()

function generateGrids() {
  for (let i = 0; i < gridRows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < gridCols; j++) {
      const cell = document.createElement('div')

      cell.classList.add('cell')
      cell.dataset.row = i
      cell.dataset.col = j

      userGrid.appendChild(cell)
      enemyGrid.appendChild(cell)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.grid {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 4em;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 1px solid #b4b4ff;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid user-grid"></div>
  <div class="grid enemy-grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+appendChild+same+element) of [How to appendChild(element) many times. (The same element)](/q/36635392/4642212). Or simply read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `appendChild` on an element which is already in the DOM will move the original element to the new position.

Instead, clone the element, then append:

```js
const gridRows = 10
const gridCols = 10
const userGrid = document.querySelector('.user-grid')
const enemyGrid = document.querySelector('.enemy-grid')

generateGrids()

function generateGrids() {
  for (let i = 0; i < gridRows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < gridCols; j++) {
      const cell = document.createElement('div')

      cell.classList.add('cell')
      cell.dataset.row = i
      cell.dataset.col = j

      userGrid.appendChild(cell.cloneNode(true))
      enemyGrid.appendChild(cell.cloneNode(true))
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.grid {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 4em;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 1px solid #b4b4ff;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid user-grid"></div>
  <div class="grid enemy-grid"></div>
</div>
```